# How to declare a function once in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, function, variable-declaration

I have a WordPress website with Ad Inserter plugin.

This plugin has different blocks where I can insert a php code to show it in different position of the post (e.g. after title, after paragraph 1, after content...)

I have a php script and I want to print it in the post 2 times in 2 different positions. The problem is that I prefer to declare `sample` variable one time only.

So I created 2 blocks:

BLOCK 1:

```
<?php
$sample="test";
print $sample ?>
```

BLOCK 2:

```
<?php
print $sample ?>
```

The first block is correctly rendered in the page but the second one shows a blank space instead of `test`. If I copy the two codes in one block only, everything works but I need to show them in two different positions.

This is a basic WordPress/PHP question. 
How do I edit the second block without declaring `sample` variable again?

Comment: Are you sure you are sharing whole code? It looks like you are assigning value to Variable, but you are saying Function, is the $sample=test; inside a function tag i.e. function xyx(){  $sample = test ;}?

Comment: I'm sorry, the code is right. I mean variable, not function.

Comment: Its ok. It is strange that why your variable's value is being overwritten to empty on second call? Is there something else might be going on which reassign your variable $sample to ="" before your second call which is why it is printing blank value?

Comment: I guess the plugin renders the blocks as indipendent, so the 2nd block doesn't get the value of the variable assigned in the 1st block..

Comment: Hard to pinpoint without knowing all the workings the plugin. Maybe posting to plugin support forum might get you solution. Also I suggest you add plugin name and url in the question and more detail, maybe someone familiar with that plugin can shed some light how those ads values are assigned in that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you do not have any functions - `$sample` is a variable. It is also not being set correctly, you need to wrap `test` in quotes, like `"test"`.

Depending on where you are placing this code, the variable `$sample` is not being set in the second "block", so when you echo the value, it's blank.

To create a function that you can use to output the same value consistently, add a new function to your `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/functions.php` file. Replace `YOUR-THEME` with the name of your theme (and if you are using something you downloaded, I would suggest creating a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) first).

**Add new function**

```
// create a function 
function echo_sample(){
    // set the variable $sample to a value of "test"
    $sample = "test";

    // echo the value of the $sample variable
    echo $sample; 
}
```

You then call this function from other places in your code by placing it inside a PHP tag, like so:

**Call function**

```
<?php echo_sample(); ?>
```

Which will result in "test" being printed to the screen.

Comment: When I use the call function, I guess it runs the function. So, if I use 2 "echo" in a post, it runs it twice. :(

The problem is that the code above is just a sample, but in the reality I have a PHP script that calls Amazon API and I can't call them twice in a page (I hate overloading). 

Unfortunately with your solution it looks like the problem is still there. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure I understand - you want to call an amazon api and cache the results so that the page doesn't make two api requests?

Answer (score 0):

To create a function you need to use the keyword `function` then the function name and after that it's body.

```
function function_name($par=1){
    //function body here.
}
```

to call the function :  `function_name();`.